# Question on transformations & symmetry

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the question i have been given i have been asked to show how one equation becomes another after making the x value into -x, i don't understand how to interpret it, heres the actual question.

> Consider the hyperbola $\frac{2}{x-2}$
>
> Show that when x is replaced by -x the equation becomes y = - $\frac{2}{x+2}$

Thanks.

Comment: The question is asking you to replace every instance of $x$ in $\frac{2}{x-2}$ with $-x$, and simplify it to $- \frac{2}{x-2}$.

Comment: my bad, i edited its supposed to be x+2 not x-2

Comment: The process is the same: replace every instance of $x$ with $-x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show this you can say $f(x)=\frac{2}{x-2}$ and then xalculate $f(-x)$. So we have:
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{-x-2}=\frac{2}{(-1)\cdot(x+2)}=-\frac{2}{x+2}$$